# How to measure air quality (especially PM2.5) from distance (scanning like a LiDAR)?

Tags: sensor, design, laser, optics, gas

I have a bit of experience in measuring PM2.5 (fine particles in the (ambient) air 2.5 micrometres or less in size) using [PMS5003](https://github.com/avaldebe/AQmon/blob/master/Documents/PMS5003_LOGOELE.pdf) sensor. This sensor uses laser, photodiode and the fact that the air flow through the sensor has constant speed due to applied fan.

However, this sensor can measure PM2.5 only in one location. I want a device which would be capable of measuring air quality (particulate matter or anything else) from distance. So, in order to make a map of pollutants in the city I wouldn't need to provide sensor for every x meters. I'd like to just locate the LiDAR-like sensor on some high tower and scan some area.

What should I use to build such a device?

Comment: How far are we talking?

Comment: I don't think this is doable without unreasonably powerful lasers for the LIDAR.

Comment: Any distance longer than 250 m would be better than what I have now.

Comment: @Defozo The only way I could imagine measuring Very long ranges would be with very powerful lasers. We're talking some of the very expensive, *illegal* ones.

Comment: What distance can I achieve with the legal ones?

Comment: Or can I use somehow 'illegal' ones in a non-dangerous way?

Comment: that I'm not even sure. My best guess is that the LiDAR operation you're speaking of uses IR excitation to measure CO2 and CO, so with a reasonable camera and a decent exposure, maybe 100 meters. That's something I haven't done in vast quantities.I would just go with a cheap setup, such as a Carbon monoxide sensor: https://www.adafruit.com/products/3199, and arduino nano for about 4$, and a cheapo 5$ lipo battery. for about 25$ a piece, you get about 20 of those before you even hit the price of a  large laser

Comment: @Defozo you could, in theory. you'd have to point it straight up, and if an illegal laser hits a plane, it is almost the same as manslaughter in the US.

Comment: My current device costs me about $125 (the sensor itself, communication module, PCB, metal housing, antenna etc.) and in this price things like soldering, mounting, looking for the right place to mount are not included. So, I thought that some scanning device would be wise not just because of the data it could provide but from economical point of view as well.
How should I search for elements to make that 100 meters LiDAR that you mentioned?

Answer (score 5):

Backscatter (standoff) lidar for fine particulate matter concentrations is very hard, but doable.  There is a company in France that offers it (LEOSPHERE), but their website is down.  I found that through [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1674200115002059) paper.

There are also people that do this or attempt to do this [for roadside emissions sensing](https://www3.epa.gov/ttnemc01/meetnw/2002op/epa_hans.pdf).

Both of these systems use ND-YAG lasers that are frequency tripled into the UV.  NG-Yag lasers can be expensive (>$1000 to well over $100k), depending on power, rep rate and pulse size.  They also need sophisticated free-space optical setups for both the laser itself (including the frequency triple stage) and the backscatter return path.  On top of this they need sophisticated data analysis tools in order to get usable numbers out.  These are primarily research tools.